# Update LayoutInflator FrameLayout id with position

Tags: android

I am working on a horizontal scroll, which initially has only one single `framelayout`. In the framelayout, I have imageview and imagebutton. User clicks on framelayout to add an image from the camera library. Once the image selected and loadded, it inflates the new framelayout and adding a new framelayout (imageview and imagebutton) to the right. Currently, I am allowing a user to load up to 5 images. ImageButton allows user to delete the selected framelayout.

Each inflated `framelayout` has id, and I am keep tracking of it. The issue that I have as follows:

When user deletes the first images, then my second image(framelayout) replaces but still keeps the same id. Is there a way of changing view id dynamically with a position in the layout?

In other words, if my `framelayout` position updates based on user action(for example delete action), then I want assigned id also updates.

**Image Load and Delete**

```
 @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
      if(v instanceof NetworkImageView) {
            clickedView = (NetworkImageView)v;
            showDialog(this);
      }
      else if(v instanceof ImageButton) {
            layout.removeViewAt(v.getId());
            totalImageCount--;
       }
   }
```

**Inflate and Add new FrameLayout**

```
if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {
   Uri filePath = data.getData();
   selectedPath = getRealPathFromURI(filePath);
   ImageUtil.setPic(clickedView, selectedPath);
   if(clickedView.getId() == totalImageCount && totalImageCount < 4)          
   {
      newImageView(clickedView.getId() + 1);
      totalImageCount++;
   }

private void newImageView(int id) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View rl = inflater.inflate(R.layout.relative_image, null);

        NetworkImageView niv = (NetworkImageView) rl.findViewById(R.id.imageViewAdd);
        niv.setOnClickListener(this);
        niv.setId(id);

        ImageButton imgBtn = (ImageButton) rl.findViewById(R.id.imageBtnClose);
        imgBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
        imgBtn.setId(id);

        rl.setId(id);

        ImageLoader imageLoader = CustomVolleyRequest.getInstance(this.getApplicationContext())
                .getImageLoader();
        imageLoader.get(Config.IMAGE_PATH_URL, ImageLoader.getImageListener(niv,
                R.drawable.image, android.R.drawable
                        .ic_menu_camera));
        niv.setImageUrl(selectedPath, imageLoader);

        layout.addView(rl, id);
}
```

**relative_image.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/relative"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp" >

    <com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageViewAdd"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:contentDescription="@string/description" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageBtnClose"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_close_black_24dp" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code has a number of very serious problems. I'm going to start with the misuse of the `id`s.

You shouldn't use the `id` attribute for this purpose. Consider that you insist on using the same mechanism for deleting a picture, it is better that you use the `tag` attribute. Leave the `id`'s intact and change the `tag` values of the `imgBtn`. This way when you are deleting the image your code becomes like `layout.removeViewAt(Integer.parse(v.getTag().toString()));`. Another issue in your code is that you are giving the same id to multiple widgets. This must never happen in an application because it makes it hard to track different objects, although in the case of your application it is not doing any damage.

I think there is a better way for carrying out what you want to do. In your `newImageView` function, remove the lines that change the `id`s. Then you on click function becomes like this:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch(v.getId()) {
    case R.id.imageViewAdd:
        clickedView = (NetworkImageView)v;
        showDialog(this);
        break;
    case R.id.:
        layout.removeView((FrameLayout) v.getParent());
        totalImageCount--;
        break;
    }
}
```

This code should take care of your application.

Comment: thank a lot for the explanation. I wonder how could I able to handle the following line, which is in the camera library selection part, I have also put in my question.  `if( clickedView.getId() == totalImageCount && totalImageCount < 4)`. This line looks if image is going to be replaced, then it wont create the new image.

Comment: Sorry about the delay. I need more information to be able to answer. Please elaborate your question.

Comment: Shall I use listview  to hold the position of the view? I am asking because now I am directly adding the view to the layout  as follows `layout.addView(rl, id)`;